# How to see requests to S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, request

My data transfer out charges are much higher than normal. The usage report tells me how much was transferred every hour, but I'd like to see **to where**.

Does Amazon/S3 provide info about the specific requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be out of luck to see what already happened, but you can turn on detailed logging for future requests:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

> In order to track requests for access to your bucket, you can enable
>   access logging. Each access log record provides details about a single
>   access request, such as the requester, bucket name, request time,
>   request action, response status, and error code, if any. Access log
>   information can be useful in security and access audits. It can also
>   help you learn about your customer base and understand your Amazon S3
>   bill.